# Adapting the height of RowLayout as part of ColumnLayout

Tags: qt, qml

I have a simple question - is there a way I can make my `rowLayout` change its height evenly with the rest of `columnLayout` items? Or what exactly does it prevent from adjusting its height along with the rectangles?

A simple piece of code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 30

        RowLayout {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            Rectangle {
                id: rec1
                width: 30; height: 30
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                color: "darkslateblue"
            }

            Label {
                text: qsTr("Heading 1")
                font.pixelSize: 25
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rec2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "bisque"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rec3
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "bisque"
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I'm getting something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use an [`Item`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html) as a [`RowLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html) container:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 30

        Item{
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            RowLayout {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                anchors.fill: parent
                Rectangle {
                    id: rec1
                    width: 30; height: 30
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                    color: "darkslateblue"
                }

                Label {
                    text: qsTr("Heading 1")
                    font.pixelSize: 25
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rec2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "bisque"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rec3
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            color: "bisque"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]